# Installing old version of mysql

Tags: mysql, debian-wheezy

I'm trying to troubleshoot a database import problem and want to duplicate the environment onto another server. This will require installing an older version of mysql, but the packages that are listed are only showing a recent version. I'm currently running debian wheezy 7.1 and what was installed was the packaged 5.5.31. What is the official way to install an older copy? I guess I could hunt around Google and hope to find some files of the same version to install from source, but this doesn't seem like a reliable method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing and configuring from scratch?  MySQL is available all the way back to 5.0 on their webiste - http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php

There's a good guide here for a legacy version on Ubuntu;

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56084/installing-old-mysql-server-4-1-on-ubuntu-11-04

Shouldn't need too much alteration to work on Debian, if any at all.